# Apache Tomcat/8.0.8.5.4 - possible looping process with tomcat java process

Tags: java, apache, tomcat8, embedded-tomcat-8

I setup Tomcat 8.5.4 on linux and deployed my war. I made changes to catalina.sh for JAVA_OPTS and running fine until last week. I got to know:

```
$top -p 10120
cpu time: 95%
```

PID 10120 running under the ID root executing the command java has consumed over 13228 minutes of CPU time. I don't have any idea why this is happening as no body accessing the application ever and there is no load yet.

Do you have any idea any short comings or bugs on Tomcat 8.5.4?

Comment: Running tomcat as root? Risky.

Comment: using sudo.....

Comment: If it's running as `root`, that doesn't make it any less risky.